# Is there a custom extension that I need to make RabbitMQ UI/Management to show my connection, channels e.t.c

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I have set up RabbitMQ and it's running well and I can be able to connect to it in Python and even create queues as shown below

```
import pika

url = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f'
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='new_tweets_exchange')
channel.queue_declare(queue='new_tweets_queue')
channel.queue_bind(exchange='new_tweets_exchange', queue='new_tweets_queue', routing_key='new_tweets')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='new_tweets_exchange', routing_key='new_tweets', body='Hello World!')

print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume("new_tweets_queue", callback, auto_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
connection.close()
```

Using `rabbitmqctl list_bindings` I can be able to see the bindings I've created.
However, If I go to the management UI, all values are zero. Any suggestions/ideas on what I need to do to get them to reflect on the UI?
[image: Management UI]

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what your question is..
in the header you ask for "channels and connections". they are found in the "Connections" and "Channels" section of the webpage.

the the text you ask for "list-bindings". they are listed in "Exchanges"-section for the given exchange.